# Strange 64-bit time format from game, you can recognize it?

Tags: date, delphi, time, 64-bit

i capture this 64-bit time format from a game and trying to understand it.
I can not use a date delta because every now and then the value totally changes and even becomes negative as seen below.

```
v1:int64=-5990085973098618987;   //2021-01-25 13:30:00
v2:int64=-5990085973321147595;   //4 mins later
v3:int64=6140958949625363349;    //7 mins later
v4:int64=6140958948894898101;    //11 mins later
v5:int64=-174740204032730139;    //16 mins later
v6:int64=-174740204054383467;    //18 mins later
v7:int64=-6490439358095090795;   //23 mins later
```

I tried to split the 64-bit into two 32-bit containers to get low and high part. still strange values.
I also tried using pdouble(@value)^ to get float value of the 64-bit data, still strange values.
So kind of running out of ideas, maybe some kind of bitfield data or something else going on.

```
hipart: -1394675573 | lopart: 1466441621  | hex: acdef08b|57681f95 | swap: -7701322112560996692
hipart: -1394675573 | lopart: 1243913013  | hex: acdef08b|4a249b35 | swap: 3862721007994330796
hipart: 1429803424  | lopart: -458425451  | hex: 553911a0|e4acfb95 | swap: -7639322244965910187
hipart: 1429803424  | lopart: -1188890699 | hex: 553911a0|b922f7b5 | swap: -5334757052947285675
hipart: -40684875   | lopart: -760849435  | hex: fd9332b5|d2a65be5 | swap: -1919757392230050819
hipart: -40684875   | lopart: -782502763  | hex: fd9332b5|d15bf495 | swap: -7641381711494605827
hipart: -1511173174 | lopart: -1467540587 | hex: a5ed53ca|a8871b95 | swap: -7702413578668347995
```

Any ideas welcomed, thanks in advance
//mbs

--EDIT: So far, thanks to Martin Rosenau we are able to encode like this:

```
func mulproc_nfsw(i:int64;key:uint32):int64;
begin
 if (blnk i) or (blnk key) then exit;
 p:pointer=@i;
 hi:uint32=uint32(p+4)^; //30864159 (hex: 01d6f31f)
 lo:uint32=uint32(p)^; //748455936 (hex: 2c9c8800)
 hi64:int64=hi*key; //0135b55a acdef08b <-- keep
 lo64:int64=lo*key; //1d566e0b a65f2800 <-- keep
 q:pointer=@result; //-5990085971773806592
 uint32(q+4)^:=hi64; //acdef08b
 uint32(q)^:=lo64; //a65f2800
end;
```

```
func encode_time_nfsw(j:juncture):int64;
begin
 if blnk j then exit; //input: '2021-01-25 13:37:07'
 key:uint32=$A85A2115; //encode key
 ft:int64=j.filetime; //hex: 01d6f31f 2c9c8800
 result:=mulproc_nfsw(ft,key);
end;
```

--EDIT2: Finally, thanks to fpiette we are able to decode also:

```
func decode_time_nfsw(i:int64):juncture;
begin
 if blnk i then exit; //input: -5990085971773806592
 key:uint32=$3069263D; //decode key
 ft:int64=mulproc_nfsw(i,key);
 result.setfiletime(ft);
end;
```

Comment: Seems that the high 32 bits do not change often; do you know how often/when the high 32 bits change? It is conspicuous that the low nibble (low 4 bits) is always 5 and that the difference between the high words is always the same.

Comment: About every 5 min or so, and in between looks like not changing so much

Comment: If a 100ns time base (such as a "[FILETIME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-filetime)" ) is used, the high 32 bits change about every 7.2 minutes. It seems that the low and the high 32 bits are encoded (maybe encrypted) independently of each other.  Obviously, the high 32 bits are multiplied by A85A2115 (hex), maybe after adding some offset and only the low bits of the product are taken.

Comment: @Martin Rosenau     I did try to compare it to filetime (64-bit) and unix time / time_t (also 64-bit) but values did not match. Yes i could be worried some sort of coding going on. The values comes from my reverse engineered game server for this game, and the values are used in context with the game chat on xmpp protocol, so it is possible they added some strangeness to the values...

Comment: It could be a Time Stamp Counter value. This time is given by a 64bit register and read by RDTSC instruction. To get real time, you need to get once the actual real time clock time to get the offset. For more details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter

Comment: The value could also result of an obfuscation such as XORing the actual value with a 64bit constant.

Comment: How do you know that the value represents a time?

Comment: @Olivier because when i type MESSAGE in to the ingame chat, it sends this to my xmpp server:

`<message to='channel.EN__2@conference.192.168.1.120' type='groupchat'>
 <channel>Chat_All</channel>
 <body>
  &lt;ChatMsg Type=&quot;0&quot; Uid=&quot;11111111&quot; Time=&quot;-2676507135648260331&quot; Cs=&quot;4292327238845499045&quot;&gt;
  &lt;From&gt;MORTENBSCOM&lt;/From&gt;
  &lt;Msg&gt;MESSAGE&lt;/Msg&gt;
  &lt;/ChatMsg&gt;
 </body>
</message>`

Comment: @fpiette the clients actually receives time from server, but only once at startup, it calls "systeminfo" from server and get the time there. but the time value still changing radically on an interval, so the clients would need to get an offset from the server ? i monitor all the traffic and clients (game) are not asking for anything when left on idle but values still changing...

Comment: If the time change radically, it is likely an obfuscation. The most probably is a simple XOR but could be anything which is easily revertible. It could also be encrypted using a shared key algorithm such as DES.

Comment: dam, it sounds like it is going to be a hard one to crack, and i can't get the game to respond to anything i send back to it, before understanding so a bit stuck here for now it seems, but thanks for any inputs so far, it was interesting feedback to think about. also that cs checksum value driving me nuts :)

Comment: @MartinRosenau What makes you think the multiplier is 0xA85A2115?

Comment: @fpiette The high word increases by 0xA85A2115 every time it changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked my suspicion that the high and the low 32 bits are simply multiplied by A85A2115 (hex):

We get a [FILETIME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-filetime) structure. Then we perform a 32x32->32 bit multiplication (this means we throw away the high 32 bits of the 64 bits result) of the high and the low word independently.

Example:

```
25 Jan 2021 13:37:07 (and some milliseconds)
```

Unencrypted FILETIME:

```
High dword = 1D6F31F (hex)
Low dword  = 2C9CA481 (hex)
```

Multiplication

```
High dword: 1D6F31F * A85A2115  = 135B55AACDEF08B (hex)
Low dword:  2C9CA481 * A85A2115 = 1D5680CA57681F95 (hex)
```

Now only take the low 32 bits of the results:

```
High dword: ACDEF08B (hex)
Low dword:  57681F95 (hex)
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to do the the "reverse operation"; I did it by searching for the result in a loop with the following pseudo-code:

```
encryptedValue = 57681F95 (hex)
originalValue = 0
product = 0
while product not equal to encryptedValue
    // 32-bit addition discarding carry:
    product = product + A85A2115 (hex) 
    originalValue = originalValue + 1
end_of_while_loop
```

We get the following results:

```
25 Jan 2021 13:37:07 => acdef08b|57681f95
25 Jan 2021 13:40:51 => acdef08b|4a249b35
25 Jan 2021 13:45:07 => 553911a0|e4acfb95
25 Jan 2021 13:49:03 => 553911a0|b922f7b5
25 Jan 2021 13:53:53 => fd9332b5|d2a65be5
25 Jan 2021 13:55:50 => fd9332b5|d15bf495
25 Jan 2021 14:00:39 => a5ed53ca|a8871b95
```

**Addendum**

The reverse operation seems to be done by multiplying with 3069263D (hex) (and only using the low 32 bits).

Encrypting:

```
2C9CA481 * A85A2115 = 1D5680CA57681F95
=> Result: 57681F95
```

Decrypting:

```
57681F95 * 3069263D = 10876CAF2C9CA481
=> Result: 2C9CA481
```

Comment: Does the time (2021-01-25 13:30:00) given by the OP result in the value he gave (-5990085973098618987 = 0xACDE F08B 5768 1F95)?

Comment: @MartinRosenau Wow Martin that is nice work man. I too wondered how you spotted that A85A2115 value :) Now I can encode to that format and it looks good. Yes - a bit funny it is off by 7 mins and 7 secs, because i made an effort to press ENTER at exactly 13:30:00 but I am going to assume that comes from a delay inside the game or something. I am going to accept your answer (of course) but I have not yet managed to decode it (my language went into infitnite loop lol) can you come up with a more optimal method to decode ? perhaps division as encoding was done with multiplication ?

Comment: IMO This answer is wrong. The first example the OP gave do not translate to the int64 value shown when doing the computation shown.

Comment: @fpiette The time is not exactly 13:37:07, but it is 13:37:07 and some milliseconds. The tool decoding the FILETIME value to a readable string I used did not show the milliseconds, so I cannot tell you the exact time represented by that value.

Comment: @mortenbs It was conspicuous that the upper 32 bits change about every 5 minutes only. So I suspected that this word is the upper word of a 64 bit counter which makes 2^32 ticks in about 5 minutes. Of course, the "unencrypted" word would increment by 1 every 5 minutes. Next thing I did was simply subtracting the values; I saw that the difference is always A85A2115. If the encrypted value changes by A85A2115 each time the unencrypted value is incremented, it is obvious that encryption is done by multiplying with A85A2115.

Comment: Note that 0xA85A2115 * 0x3069263D is equal to 1 (after truncation to 32 bits), which explains why you get back the original number.

Comment: @fpiette You guys rock, now it work both ways. I have to read all of this a couple of times to fully understand how you did this :) but was able to create routines based on your information and included as an edit to the original post. How can I give credit to both of you ? -- also you guys could probably figure out that cs value which i think is a form of checksum/hash value, would you join if i make a new question about that ? Thanks to everyone who participated in this! It Works :)